# Are the collected papers of A. Einstein, entirely translated into English?

Tags: general-relativity, soft-question, specific-reference

I need some [Einstein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Einstein)'s papers translated into English. There is one complete collection of his papers but only a few of them have been translated in English. The rest are in their original language -- German, which, unfortunately, I can't read. Have you seen anywhere all of his paper translated in English?

Comment: You wrote: "There is one complete collection of his papers". Could you please specify which collection you meant? There is, at least, one more that I am aware of - published in 1965 but it is translation into Russian (four volumes).

Comment: Do you know you can accept an answer (if it's useful to you) by clicking in the tick or check button that are on the left margin of the answers? Sorry if you already knew.

Answer (score 3):

The published papers from the 1902-1920 are translated in the collected papers of Albert Einstein, which is a series of books you can find in many libraries, homepage here: http://press.princeton.edu/catalogs/series/cpe.html , this series is full of junk like private correspondence and such, but the publications are in there too.

From 1933 onward, the work is published in English, and this includes EPR, wormholes, unified theories, Einstein-Infeld-Hoffman approximation, and others. So there is only a 12 year gap--- 1921-1932 unfortunately some of his most productive years. The 1920s papers include great classics, and will be published in English eventually. There are good extant translations of the laser/BEC paper, the A-B spontaneous/stimulated emmission coefficients paper, and perhaps the seminal 1924 Hamilton-Jacobi equation quantum mechanics paper.

It would be good if somebody did a translation of the scientific publications only, leaving the personal junk for another time.

Comment: Thanks Ron. This is my impression too. Now, I need for instance Einstein A., Ehrenfest P., Z.Physik, 19, 301-306 (1923) and can't find it translated. There are several other from the same period you mention that haven't been translated. Isn't it a shame to have such a great scientist not fully available to the English-reading audience.

Comment: If you post an online link to a German version, someone might translate it. You could also try to to Babelfish it and figure out what they are doing from context.